# HttpClient 4.5.2 - SSL cert issue

Tags: ssl, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am using httpclient 4.5.2 to call proxy server.

```
HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(proxyHost, proxyPort, https);
HttpHost target = new HttpHost(ip, 443, "https");
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(target, httppost );
```

Below is the error i get:-

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.handleUnknownRecord(InputRecord.java:671)
        at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:504)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1312)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1323)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:394)
        at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:353)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:141)
        at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:388)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:88)
        at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:184)
        at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:117)
```

*May I know this error is related to cert problem? Because I already add the cert to truststore.*

Comment: Any one can help?

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
> ```
>
> May I know this error is related to cert problem? Because I already add the cert to truststore.

This is not a problem of a certificate. The server you access does not do a proper TLS handshake.

> I am using httpclient 4.5.2 to call proxy server.

HTTPS over a HTTP proxy server starts with a plain text HTTP CONNECT request which then established a tunnel. Only after this tunnel is established the TLS handshake is done with the original target server.

Comment: Sorry, I could not get you. I am accessing proxy server(https) and then httpclient will execute and pass in third party URL - target(https).

Comment: What can I do with the TLS?

Comment: While you declare some variable called proxy in your edited post you don't use it. I very much doubt that it will be magically applied this way. And TLS (or SSL or SSL/TLS) is just the protocol which make HTTPS out of HTTP, i.e. HTTPS is HTTP inside a TLS connection.